Laravel Blade functionality not working on 20i Laravel server
I am working on a project as in intern, for a website management/creation company. I have created a web side application that will help with managing wordpress plugins and websites.
My boss wanted to host my application through 20i's cloud service. I have a laravel cloud server, and i believe I have set up my project correctly the database and .env file should be correct and the php version is 8.3 i ran migrations and the composer install, and everything seemed to connect and work fine. Everything does almost work fine.
The domain is up and points to the correct file and when I go to the domain i get the home page I had created.
The issue is the blade functions are not working. For example two of the things I am trying to do such as

@if($upcomingPayments->isEmpty())
and
@extends('layouts.app') @section('content')

just show up as plain text. They are just plain text on the site and do not do their desired function. Is there some code I need to wrap them in?
Just wondering if anyone had encountered something like this or had any general input.
I tried a fresh hosting of the project and checking to make sure versions were compatible. I do not know really where to go on how to fix this as I am still relatively knew to programming.

what url are you visitn on your site?  Does it have a route?  Is the code working perfectly locally?  Is local Windows and remote linux?  If so there might be an issue with case of filenames?
